# Javascript: calling methods in classes with this

Tags: javascript, class, this

Now my Code works as intended, but I don´t understand the keyword `this` at this one place. 
When I try to call the `mainLoop` method in the requestAnimationFrame with `window.requestAnimationFrame(this.mainLoop);` it doesn´t work.

When I tried it like I did in my example it worked, but I didn´t understand why I couldn´t call the mainLoop method with `this`, while being able to call all the other methods in this class with `this.methodName();`.

```
class Game{
  constructor(objects){
    //some stuff
  }

  temp(){
    a.mainLoop();
  }

  mainLoop(){

    // some other Methods are being called here

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.temp);
  }
}

var a = new Game(input);
```

I hope I was able to explain, my problem.

Comment: The value of this changes inside the handler if you aren’t using an arrow function or explicitly binding this with bind().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback you passed into `window.requestAnimationFrame` will run in the different context, where `this` will not be instance of your current object anymore.
As a workaround you can pass `this.temp.bind(this)` instead or use arrow function `() => this.temp()`.